# How to create an automatic form generator based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am trying to create a form which will generate different levels of forms based on the user input.

An example of this is 
"How many levels are there?" -User input 3-
Three separate levels will be generated each with the same questions. In this there will be a question asking "How many objects are there?" the same will happen here in that multiple options will be generated.

[Rough sketch of how the form would be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biuFS.png)

The problem I've been having with this is allocating ids and then being able to fetch them after so that they can be referenced for use and MySQL later down the line.

```
function generateForm(){
var number = document.getElementById('number_of_levels').value;
var div = document.getElementById('levels');
//  div.innerHTML += " " +number;

var heading = document.createElement("P");
heading.innerHTML = "Level " + number;    
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(heading);

var objects = document.createElement("P");

objects.innerHTML = "How many objects is the badge comprised of?";        
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(objects);

var num_objects_input = document.createElement("input");
num_objects_input.type = "number";
num_objects_input.id = "number_objects" +number;
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(num_objects_input);



//num_objects.onchange = function(){addObject(num_objects.id)};  

//div for the following levels
var ind_levels_div = document.createElement("div");
ind_levels_div.id = "level_" +number;
document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(ind_levels_div);
num_objects_input.onchange = function(){additionalObject()};

}


function additionalObject(){
var number = document.getElementById("number_objects" +number).value;

var objects_number = document.createElement("P");
    objects_number.innerHTML = "Object " + number;    
    document.getElementById("level_" +number).appendChild(objects_number);
}
```

The result I'm getting is the form won't generate any Object form elements but will make the Levels.

Comment: It's hard to understand your intents. Can you make any demo, or an html file containing the output you want to obtain for some `level` value?

Comment: @mrJoe I've added an image hopefully explaining it better.

Comment: Please provide the initial html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building the form this code works fine. If you want to retrieve data then you should add a name attribute what data you want to retrieve.

```js
function generateForm() {
  var number = 0;
  number = document.getElementById('number_of_levels').value;
  var div = document.getElementById('levels');
  //  div.innerHTML += " " +number;
  if (number > 0) {
    document.getElementById('levels_btn').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < number; index++) {
    var heading = document.createElement("h4");
    heading.innerHTML = "Level " + (index + 1);
    document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(heading);
    var objects = document.createElement("p");

    objects.innerHTML = "How many objects is the badge comprised of?";
    document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(objects);
    var num_objects_input = document.createElement("input");
    num_objects_input.type = "number";
    num_objects_input.id = "number_objects" + (index + 1);
    document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(num_objects_input);
    var submit = document.createElement("button");
    submit.type = "button";
    submit.innerHTML = 'objects';
    submit.id = "submit" + (index + 1);
    submit.onclick = additionalObject;
    document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(submit);

    var objectdiv = document.createElement("div");
    objectdiv.id = "objects_level" + (index + 1);
    objectdiv.className = 'objects_level';
    document.getElementById('levels').appendChild(objectdiv);

  }

}

function additionalObject() {
  //console.log(Number(this.id.replace("submit", "")));
  var pos = Number(this.id.replace("submit", ""));
  var number = document.getElementById('number_objects' + pos).value;
  for (let index = 0; index < number; index++) {
    var objects_number = document.createElement("p");
    objects_number.innerHTML = "Object " + (index + 1);
    document.getElementById("objects_level" + pos).appendChild(objects_number);

  }

}
```

```css
.levels {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.objects_level {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Level</h3>
<form action="/" method="get">
  <input type='number' name='number_of_levels' id='number_of_levels' />
  <button type='button' id='levels_btn' onclick='generateForm()' />Levels</button>
  <div id='levels' class='levels'></div>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

You can read the article https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp for getting the idea of how from action works according to retrieve the data

Comment: That suits my needs really well, the problem I was facing was avoiding using buttons but I was running into an issue of not being able to go back and get different IDs. This avoids that so thank you!